# Weird output from 'git log --graph' when trying to do nested sub-groups of commits

Tags: git, gitk

So I've been experimenting with groups of commits as discussed here -- [Is there a way to group commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380222/is-there-a-way-to-group-commits-in-git) and here -- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27722221

Having simple groups of commits by using `git merge --no-ff` worked, but then I decided to try groups of nested sub-groups, and when I tried to view the result with `git log --graph` and `gitk` I got some weird output.

The test repo I'm using is at https://github.com/maratbn/test_nested_sub_groups_of_commits

This repo contains 2 groups of commits, first one for **Feature 1** and a second for **Feature 2**.

Now, the group for **Feature 2** itself contains 2 nested sub-groups of commits, one for **Feature 2A** and another for **Feature 2B**.

All of the commits themselves are correctly identifying all of their parents and children, and `git log --graph` seems to work correctly just for the `feature2` branch:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   8e4b5f4 (HEAD -> feature2) Merge branch 'feature2b' into feature2
|\  
| * 0ce0350 (feature2b) Feature 2B commit 3.
| * c935021 Feature 2B commit 2.
| * 0bb1c7d Feature 2B commit 1.
|/  
*   58df7c0 Merge branch 'feature2a' into feature2
|\  
| * 682a2ab (feature2a) Feature 2A commit 3.
| * 0f567b0 Feature 2A commit 2.
| * 77a551a Feature 2A commit 1.
|/              (...here the branch was switched to 'feature2'...)
*   1895612 Merge branch 'feature1' (...into 'master'...)
|\  
| * 3809d12 (feature1) Feature 1, 3rd commit.
| * ed91ea8 This is for feature 1, 2nd commit.
| * ffe515d First commit for feature 1.
|/  
* 228a1ab Added 'test1.txt'.
```

But after I `git merge --no-ff feature2` into `master` (to create groups themselves having nested sub-groups) same command produces this weird output:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline

01  *   d6cde88 Merge branch 'feature2'
02  |\  
03  | *   8e4b5f4 (feature2) Merge branch 'feature2b' into feature2
04  | |\  
05  | | * 0ce0350 (feature2b) Feature 2B commit 3.
06  | | * c935021 Feature 2B commit 2.
07  | | * 0bb1c7d Feature 2B commit 1.
08  | |/  
09  | *   58df7c0 Merge branch 'feature2a' into feature2
10  | |\  
11  |/ /  
12  | * 682a2ab (feature2a) Feature 2A commit 3.
13  | * 0f567b0 Feature 2A commit 2.
14  | * 77a551a Feature 2A commit 1.
15  |/              (...here the branch was switched to 'feature2'...)
16  *   1895612 Merge branch 'feature1'
17  |\  
18  | * 3809d12 (feature1) Feature 1, 3rd commit.
19  | * ed91ea8 This is for feature 1, 2nd commit.
20  | * ffe515d First commit for feature 1.
21  |/  
22  * 228a1ab Added 'test1.txt'.
```

Notice how the commit `58df7c0` is displayed as if it is connected to the `master` branch even though it was made in the `feature2` branch, and commits `77a551a` to `682a2ab` are displayed as nested off the `master` branch rather than `feature2`.

Does this look like a bug with `git log --graph`?

Comment: What exact version of Git is this?

Comment: It looks like you ran the `git log` output through some software that inserted a backslash in front of each asterisk. Other than that, this looks normal enough. The merge into `feature2` is displayed as a commit "on the feature2 mainline", because it *is* such a commit. The three commits below it (all only on "feature2a" initially) are now on "feature2" as well and there's no reason that `git log --graph` sees to indent them more, though if it did so, the display would be easier to eyeball.

Comment: @Matt git version 2.17.1

Comment: `git` does not keep track of branches ; when a commit is created, there is no information saying "this commit was created when the active branch was `feature2a`". The graph you see is consistent, it displays (correctly) that `77a551a` forked from commit `1895612`, and that the history after that was merged into your current branch at commit `d6cde88`. And all of these commits are now also part of your current branch's history.

Comment: @torek Thanks for noticing the issue with the backslashes, I removed them.  Regarding git not having a reason to indent the 3 commits 77a551a, 0f567b0, and 682a2ab it seems to me they should be indented because the commit 58df7c0 was never merged directly into 'master', and is displayed indented.  Furthermore, I think it is odd that git rendered connecting links on lines 10 and 11 as there is no actual direct connection to 'master' at that point.

Comment: The display at lines 10-11 shows that the commit at line 9 (`58df7c0 Merge branch 'feature2a' into feature2`) has two parents, namely commits `1895612` (1st parent) and `682a2ab` (2nd parent). `git log` draws the first parent connection as a vertical bar and the 2nd parent connection as a backslash, then takes as many additional lines as are needed to bring the two parent connections down to join the commit or line-leading-to-commit necessary to let you find, by eyeball, the two parents. Line 11's two forward slashes achieve this.

Comment: @torek @LeGEC really appreciate your help explaining the output of `git --graph`!  Your comments are the answers to my question.  Thank you!  I was able to use git "empty" commits as a workaround to the default way git renders graphs to be able to nest and sub-nest groups of commits -- https://github.com/maratbn/test_nested_sub_groups_of_commits/tree/master--w-empty-commits